# Не доходит dropdown в письме обратного звонка

Tags: php, javascript, html, email, callback

Есть сайт, на котором я пытаюсь установить функцию обратного звонка через модальное окно. Имя и телефон доходят отлично, но никак не могу добиться значения из dropdown. В php и js не силён. Ниже приведу код, в котором какие я только манипуляции не совершал, всё ровно у меня не получилось. Может подскажете где ошибка? Файл HTML:

```
<div class="popup" id="request">
    <div class="popup_h1">Оставить заявку</div>
    <div class="popup_h2">Заполните форму, и мы свяжемся<br />с вами в ближайшее время</div>
    <form>
        <em>Имя</em>
        <label class="name left required"><input type="text" name="name" class="input_name" placeholder="Татьяна Иванова"></label><br>
        <em>Телефон</em>

        <label class="phone top request"><input type="text" name="phone2" class="input_ph2" placeholder="+375..."></label>
<select name="dropdown" size="1">
<option value="option1">Сейчас</option>
<option value="option2">Через 15 минут</option>
<option value="option3">Через 30 минут</option>
</select>
<br>
<input id=u2 name="usluga" type="hidden" value="">
<input id=r2 name="referer" type="hidden" value="">
<input id=n2 name="phrase" type="hidden" value="">
<input  name="ccall" type="hidden" value="2">                   

        <input name="request" type="button" class="bttn bttn2 button noselect" value="Оставить заявку на консультацию">
    </form>
</div>
```

Файл под названием - scripts.js

```
    var $form = $(this).parent(),
        name = $('input[name="name"]', $form).val(),
        phone = $('input[name="phone2"]', $form).val(),
        email = $('input[name="email"]', $form).val(),
        option1 = $('input[name="option1"]', $form).val(),
        option2 = $('input[name="option2"]', $form).val(),
        option3 = $('input[name="option3"]', $form).val(),
        option4 = $('input[name="option4"]', $form).val(),

usluga = $('input[name="usluga"]', $form).val(),
referer = $('input[name="referer"]', $form).val(),
phrase = $('input[name="phrase"]', $form).val(),
ccall = $('input[name="ccall"]', $form).val(),
        ques = $('textarea[name="ques"]', $form).val(),
        sbt = $('input[type="button"]', $form).attr("name"),
        submit = $('input[name='+sbt+']', $form).val();
    var ref = $('input[name="referer"]').val();
    var ref = ref+'\nutm-метки:'+request_url;
    var formname = $('input[name="formname"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: "name="+name+"&usluga="+usluga+"&referer="+referer+"&phrase="+phrase+"&ccall="+ccall+"&phone="+phone+"&"+sbt+"="+submit+"&email="+email+"&option1="+option1+"&formname="+formname+"&ref="+ref
    }).always(function() {
        //метрики
        //ga('send', 'event', ''+sbt, ''+sbt, ''+sbt);
        thx();
    });
}
```

});

И файл отвечающий за письмо, под названием - respod.php

```
$name ="";
$phone ="";
$dropdown ="";

        if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name']; } 
        if (isset($_POST['dropdown'])) {$dropdown = $_POST['dropdown']; } 
        if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone'];} 
        if (isset($_POST['phone2'])) {$phone.= $_POST['phone2'];}
        if (isset($_POST['phone3'])) {$phone.= $_POST['phone3'];} 
echo  "name = ".$name."phone= ".$phone."dropdown= ".$dropdown;

/* Сюда впишите свою эл. почту */
 $address = "madest4815@gmail.com";

/* А здесь прописывается текст сообщения, \n - перенос строки */
 $mes = "Тема: Заказ обратного звонка!\nТелефон: $phone\nВопрос: $dropdown\nИмя: $name ";
```

Для Ивана:

```
var $form = $(this).parent(),
                name = $('input[name="name"]', $form).val(),
                phone = $('input[name="phone2"]', $form).val(),
                email = $('input[name="email"]', $form).val(),
                dropdown  = $('select[name="dropdown"]', $form).val(),
        usluga = $('input[name="usluga"]', $form).val(),
        referer = $('input[name="referer"]', $form).val(),
        phrase = $('input[name="phrase"]', $form).val(),
        ccall = $('input[name="ccall"]', $form).val(),
                ques = $('textarea[name="ques"]', $form).val(),
                sbt = $('input[type="button"]', $form).attr("name"),
                submit = $('input[name='+sbt+']', $form).val();
            var ref = $('input[name="referer"]').val();
            var ref = ref+'\nutm-метки:'+request_url;
            var formname = $('input[name="formname"]').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                data: "dropdown="+dropdown+"name="+name+"&usluga="+usluga+"&referer="+referer+"&phrase="+phrase+"&ccall="+ccall+"&phone="+phone+"&"+sbt+"="+submit+"&email="+email+"&option1="+option1+"&formname="+formname+"&ref="+ref
            }).always(function() {
                //метрики
                //ga('send', 'event', ''+sbt, ''+sbt, ''+sbt);
                thx();
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В js вам нужно брать значение не из `option[name=*]`, а из `select[name=dropdown]`. Примерно так

```
var $form = $(this).parent(),
    ...
    dropdown = $('select[name="dropdown"]').val(),
    ...;

...
    data: "dropdown="+dropdown+"&name="+name+"&usluga="+usluga+"&...
    ...
```

А на данный момент у вас в js не добавляется переменной по имени `dropdown` к отправке формы. Поэтому, хотя в php, вроде бы, все верно, в письме ничего не отправляется.

Comment: Теперь, когда я ввожу данные в поля и нажимаю на кнопку - Оставить заявку, ничего не происходит. Исправленный код я поместил в вопрос в самом конце, я правильно его исправил по вашему мнению?

Comment: Вы были невнимательны: `"dropdown="+dropdown+"name` вы забыли амперсанд `&` перед `name`. Сравните с моим кодом. В остальном, насколько я вижу, все в порядке.

Comment: По прежнему ничего не происходит, при нажатии на кнопку Оставить заявку. А должно выскочить окошко, о том что успешно отправлено, письма следовательно, так же не доходят (

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов те два добавленных кусочка кода, которые я предложил, не могли ничего поломать. Вы точно ничего не исправляли больше? Посмотрите в консоли браузера наличие js-ошибок. Если чисто - посмотрите на вкладке network в средствах разработчика в браузере запрос, который отправляется при отправке формы. Интересен его статус и код ответа.

Comment: Вот что показало в консоле, может поможет: ReferenceError: option1 is not defined, data: "dropdown="+dropdown+"&name="+name+"&usluga="+usluga+"&referer="+referer+"&phrase="+phrase+"&ccall="+ccall+"&phone="+phone+"&"+sbt+"="+submit+"&email="+email+"&option1="+option1+"&formname="+formname+"&ref="+ref

Comment: Всё разобрался спасибо большое!

Comment: Хорошо, с этой ошибкой разобрались. А dropdown теперь в письмах приходит?

Comment: Всё приходит, всё получилось

Comment: Отлично! Рад, что смог помочь.